# How to store username to use whole application

Tags: c#, winforms

My application in in windows form.

I want to store username and show on upper side of page in whole page.

I also want use this username in whole application like the session in Asp.net.

Comment: how many forms are there in your application??

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: And which user name are you talking about? Windows logon user name? AD user name?

Comment: @johnSaps- catch from database

Comment: @user3721563 Sudhakar is correct. you can make a class and create a static property to store your user name temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a static class which holds the username variable.

Try This:

```
public static class UtilityClass
{
   public static string UserName {get;set;}
}

//access the username as below

string name = UtilityClass.UserName;
```

Comment: still incorrect,username can't be constant field because @user3721563 gets it from database. So it should have setter too.

Answer (score 0):

Please read and use Application Settings file or Resource files.

Answer (score 0):

create a Module  which holds the username variable.

Try This:

```
Module FunctionModule
  Public UserName As String   '''Store and Retrieve user name anywhere  

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Store username in class. 
In Class:

```
public class clsdata;{puclic Static String username; }
```

In code:
after successfully login

```
clasData objclass= new clasdata(); clsData.username= username.Text;
```